# SQL SPID Blocking itself

Tags: sql-server-2000, blocking

I'm running SQL Server 2000.

I have a situation where users are timing out.

In enterprise manager I look at the locks/ProcessIDs.

I see

```
   spid 79 (Blocked By 79)
```

How is it possible for a session to block itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was introduced with Service pack 4 in SQL Server 2000. See this KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/906344  for an explanation

> When an SPID is waiting for an I/O
>   page latch, you may notice that the
>   blocked column briefly reports that
>   the SPID is blocking itself. This
>   behavior is a side effect of the way
>   that latches are used for I/O
>   operations on data pages